# Sorting a list of lists by the first element of inner list (Java or groovy)

Tags: java, list, sorting, groovy

I have a list which contains a list of strings like so...

```
 ["Running Shoes", "Men's Shoes", "Men's Walking Shoes"]
 ["Team Sports", "Ice Hockey", "Recreational Ice Skates"]
 ["Pro Sports", "Baseball", "Baseball Gloves", "Adult Gloves"]
```

I want to sort this list by the first element in the sublist, meaning the element at index 0. So in this example after the sort, the 'Running Shoes' element would be first, followed by 'Pro Sports' element and last would 'Team Sports'.

Could you someone give some pointers or share some code? In Java or Groovy.

Comment: You can write a `Comparator` and use `Collections.sort`.

Comment: `P` is less than `R` so surely `Pro Sports` will be first?

Comment: Of course Tim, you are right. Thanks for your answer, just what I needed

Comment: why the down votes for my question? Haters just hatin.

Comment: @user3223841 you get downvoted, because the question is all about what you want and not about what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In groovy:

```
list.sort { it[0][0] }
```

If you don't want to mutate the original list, and return the sorted list, you can do

```
list.sort(false) { it[0][0] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, P comes before R, so if I'm understanding the problem correctly, the order would be 'Pro Sports, Baseball', 'Running Shoes', and 'Team Sports'. You can sort this easily with Groovy like this:

```
[
     ["Running Shoes", "Men's Shoes", "Men's Walking Shoes"],
     ["Team Sports", "Ice Hockey", "Recreational Ice Skates"],
     ["Pro Sports", "Baseball", "Baseball Gloves", "Adult Gloves"]
].toSorted { a, b -> a[0] <=> b[0] }
```

The output looks like this:

```
[
    ['Pro Sports', 'Baseball', 'Baseball Gloves', 'Adult Gloves'],
    ['Running Shoes', "Men's Shoes", "Men's Walking Shoes"],
    ['Team Sports', 'Ice Hockey', 'Recreational Ice Skates']
]
```

You can also go the long way with a Comparator:

```
class ListComparator implements Comparator<List> {
    int compare(List obj1, List obj2) {
        obj1[0].compareTo(obj2[0])
    }

    boolean equals(Object obj) {
        this == obj
    }
}

[
     ["Running Shoes", "Men's Shoes", "Men's Walking Shoes"],
     ["Team Sports", "Ice Hockey", "Recreational Ice Skates"],
     ["Pro Sports", "Baseball", "Baseball Gloves", "Adult Gloves"]
].toSorted( new ListComparator()) == [
    ['Pro Sports', 'Baseball', 'Baseball Gloves', 'Adult Gloves'],
    ['Running Shoes', "Men's Shoes", "Men's Walking Shoes"],
    ['Team Sports', 'Ice Hockey', 'Recreational Ice Skates']
]
```

## Hint

You're getting down votes because you can learn this by reading Groovy's documentation.